# How to get string without <img tag in <td>

Tags: html

I want
USD 26,630 - 26,800
Eur 31,200 - 31,550

How to ignore img tag?

Html:
`</tr> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;USD</td> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;" align="center">26,630<IMG src="/images/currency_down1225069042.gif" width="5" height="9" border="0" /></td> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;" align="center">26,800</td> </tr> <tr> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;EUR</td> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;" align="center">31,200</td> <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ece8e6; color:black;" align="center">31,550<IMG src="/images/currency_down1225069042.gif" width="5" height="9" border="0" /></td> </tr>`

My [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Xm6PpN/1/)

Comment: this is not a HTML question but a scripting question such as `javascript` imo. You can use `querySelectorAll` in combination with `forEach` and `remove()` to remove all image tags from a string within JS.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do with that? Are you trying to change that in IDE by replace with regex or else...?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('<img[^/]*/>','igm'),'');
```